# Python SMTPlib: Message sending in from header

Tags: python, smtplib

In Python I'm attempting to send a message via SMTPlib. However, the message is always sending the entire message in the from header, and I have no idea how to fix it. It wasn't doing it before, but now it's always doing it. Here is my code:

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

def verify(email, verify_url):
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = 'pyhubverify@gmail.com\n'
    msg['To'] = email + '\n'
    msg['Subject'] = 'PyHub verification' + '\n'
    body = """ Someone sent a PyHub verification email to this address! Here is the link: 
    www.xxxx.co/verify/{1}
    Not you? Ignore this email.
    """.format(email, verify_url)
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login('pyhubverify@gmail.com', 'xxxxxx')
    print msg.as_string()
    server.sendmail(msg['From'], [email], body)
    server.close()
```

Is there anything wrong with it, and is there a way I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is the issue:

```
server.sendmail(msg['From'], [email], body)
```

You could fix it with:

```
server.sendmail(msg['From'], [email], msg.as_string())
```

You were sending the `body` instead of the whole message; the `SMTP` protocol expects the message to start with the headers... hence you are seeing the `body` where the headers is supposed to be.

You also need to remove the newline characters. Per [rfc2822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt) the line-feed characters are undesirable alone:

> A message consists of header fields (collectively called "the header
>      of the message") followed, optionally, by a body.  The header is a
>      sequence of lines of characters with special syntax as defined in
>      this standard. The body is simply a sequence of characters that
>      follows the header and is separated from the header by an empty line
>      (i.e., a line with nothing preceding the CRLF).

Please try the following:

```
msg = MIMEMultipart()
email = 'recipient@example.com'
verify_url = 'http://verify.example.com'
msg['From'] = 'pyhubverify@gmail.com'
msg['To'] = email
msg['Subject'] = 'PyHub verification'
body = """ Someone sent a PyHub verification email to this address! Here is the link:
www.xxxx.co/verify/{1}
Not you? Ignore this email.
""".format(email, verify_url)
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
print msg.as_string()
```

Comment: Even when I'd send it with `msg.as_string()` instead of `body` it'd get the same results.

Comment: also need to remove the `\n` characters.

Comment: That doesn't help either.